# Inserting null and string 'Null in trigger condition

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm creating a new trigger and want to have both null value and NULL string in :new.SCO_NUMBER validation. I'm getting error when i'm using both (as shown below) but when i use ':new.SCO_NUMBER IS NULL', it works fine. How to use or in this validation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_SCONUMBER_INSERT AFTER
  INSERT ON S_SYN_EAI_SCO_IN FOR EACH row DECLARE XYZ BEGIN XYZ
  SELECT XYZ
  FROM xyz
  WHERE xyz IF inserting
  AND :new.SCO_NUMBER IS (NULL
  OR 'NULL') THEN varError_Msg := 'SCO Number cannot be NULL in';
  varError_id                  := 1;
  varSucceeded                 := 'N' ;
  varErrorExists               :=1;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of T-SQL,

replace `new.SCO_NUMBER IS (NULL OR 'NULL')` with `new.SCO_NUMBER IS NULL OR new.SCO_NUMBER = 'NULL'`. This should work for you.

Comment: Do not have req. reputations :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IF inserting
  AND ( :new.SCO_NUMBER IS NULL
  OR :new.SCO_NUMBER = 'NULL') THEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
(:new.SCO_NUMBER IS NULL OR :new.SCO_NUMBER = 'NULL')
```